# duda python- pptx

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

Estoy realizando un trabajo final del grado con python, y me surgió una duda:

A través de matplotlib he creado unos gráficos y tablas que me gustaría poder pasar a powerpoint. Estoy utilizando la librería pptx para ir creando un powerpoint con todos los resultados que debo exponer en un trabajo del grado, pero no consigo encontrar la forma de pasar los gráficos y tablas directamente, ya que en los foros y guías, los pasos que dan es para construir esas tablas en ppt desde 0, y yo ya lo tengo construido, es solo pasarlo a ppt.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece! saludos.

Comment: No he usado nunca la librería `pptx`, pero he visto que tiene la capacidad de insertar imágenes en diapositivas. Eso te da un mecanismo sencillo para las gráficas, pues `matplotlib` tiene el método `plt.save_fig()` que te permite guardar la gráfica en formato PNG por ejemplo, y luego bastaría que insertaras en el powerpoint esa imagen. Para las tablas está más complicado si quieres una tabla "de verdad", pero si usas  https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image puedes generar también una imagen para la tabla e insertar esa en el ppt.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @abulafia, muchísimas gracias, probaré con lo propuesto y espero que funcione! ya te contaré el resultado jajaja gracias!

Comment: No le respondas a Comunidad, es solo un bot jaja

Comment: Hola, recuerda revisar por favor [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: @abulafia, tu comentario me ha servido de gran ayuda ya que gracias a el he podido resolver mi problema. Muchas gracias!! eres un/a crack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes una prueba de concepto. ¡Funciona!

Primero hay que tener instalado obviamente `matplotlib`, `pandas`, `python-pptx` y `numpy` (lo uso en mi caso para generar datos de ejemplo). Además hay que instalar:

```
pip install dataframe_image
```

Ahora el código. Primero creamos unos datos de prueba y los metemos en un dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

datos = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=50)
df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns=["Datos"])
```

Guardamos una tabla pandas como figura png. La tabla contiene una descripción estadística de los datos:

```
dfi.export(df.describe(), "tabla.png", fontsize=24, table_conversion="matplotlib")
```

El tamaño de 24 puntos es un tanto irrelevante, pues al final a la hora de insertar el png en el pptx se le dará a la imagen el tamaño que se quiera. Pero usando un tipo de letra grande, nos aseguramos de que el texto saldrá con buena resolución (de lo contrario, al ajustar el tamaño de la tabla al de la diapositiva ppt, si la letra era pequeña el bitmap puede quedar muy pixelado al ser ampliado).

El parámetro `table_conversion` especifica el método que usará para convertir la tabla en imagen. Por defecto usa "chrome", pero eso implica que tengas instalado chrome en tu ordenador. Entiendo que lo usa para enviarle la tabla HTML tal como la genera pandas y para que sea Chrome quien la renderiza, para después sacar una "captura de pantalla". Me parece un método excesivo y muy retorcido, aunque garantiza que la tabla se verá exactamente igual a como la ves en el Notebook.

Usando en cambio el valor "matplotlib" para la conversión, usará las capacidades de matplotlib para generar tablas, y los resultados son más que buenos en mi opinión, si bien quizás no sean exactamente iguales a los que ves en el notebook, especialmente si usaste la opción `style` de pandas para variar su aspecto.

Creemos ahora un gráfico matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(datos)
plt.savefig("grafica.png", dpi=300)
```

Y ya está todo listo para crear el powerpoint:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]

# Diapositiva del titulo
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]
title.text = "Esto es una demo"
subtitle.text = "Gráficas y tablas"

# Diapositiva con un gráfico matplotlib
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
slide.shapes.add_picture("grafica.png", left=Inches(1), top=Inches(1), height=Inches(5.5))

# Diapositiva con tabla pandas y gráfica
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
slide.shapes.add_picture("tabla.png", left=Inches(1), top=Inches(1), height=Inches(4.5))
slide.shapes.add_picture("grafica.png", left=Inches(4), top=Inches(1), height=Inches(3.5))

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Y así se ve el Powerpoint resultante!

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Estube leyendo el código de dataframe_image y la documentación de matplotlib y pptx y parece que aceptan objetos file-like, por lo que no haría falta guardar archivos realmente. Haría una respuesta expandiendo eso, pero para hacer las pruebas requiero demasiadas librerias.